# Need Some Assistance On Applying a CSS Class

Tags: html, css

Okay this is what I have.

```
BODY
{
font-family: sans-serif;
background-image: url(http://www.thexboxcloud.com/images/xboxbackground2.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: left top;
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
margin-right: 15in;

}

P
{
position: relative;
padding: 1em 1em 1 em 3em;
left: 150px;
top: auto;
border-left: purple .25cm solid;
border-top: purple 1px solid;
border-bottom: purple 1px solid;
}

P.pillow

{
position: absolute;
margin-right: 15in;
}
```

Everything works fine until I try to set a class for "pillow". I am typing it in right but it seems that one of the upper 2 overrides it.

This is what I put to apply the class:

```
<p class="pillow">
```

Now that should work.

I'm trying to make a youtube video and paypal button for "pillow" not have a border around it at all.

But when I type it in, it does not override the first p class. Also, it makes the text margin spread out to the whole page when I make the first p class a specific class as well.

Could doctype code have anything to do with it? I'm using "loose".

But I can't figure out what I can't get a specific class to work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you're using capital P. It should be p.pillow,

Comment: @TheBokiya that shouldn't matter right?. Tags and attribute names are case insensitive.

Comment: @TheBokiya CSS parsers are case insensitive when it comes to elements: http://jsfiddle.net/wQ9Ya/

Comment: Yeah you're right it shouldn't matter. Tags are not case sensitive. Though conventionally it should be in lowercase.

Comment: So you want to *remove* the border on `p.pillow`? If so, you need to override what's in the `p` rules: `border: none`.

Comment: @TheBokiya  I've tried it with a lowercase p and it still doesn't work. Any other ideas as to why the specific class won't override the global p class?

Comment: Maybe you can try `!important`

Comment: @steveax  No I'm not worried about the specific code, I just want to find a way to get the class to work. It doesn't override the global p class when I set it the paragraph.

Comment: Maybe it is doctype. I'm using loose.

I don't see why the class wouldn't work either myself.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The code does not try to remove the border in any way now. You seem to expect that a rule for `P.pillow` would prevent a rule for `P` from taking effect on a `P` element in class `pillow`. That’s not how CSS works. All rules with selectors that match an element are relevant when an element is being rendered, and if there are conflicting settings, they are resolved according to CSS cascade rules.

A simple way to prevent the border in this case is to add

```
P.pillow { border: none }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
.pillow {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 15in;
}
```

What you're trying to do in your code above is select any p elements inside your class .pillow which would read

```
.pillow p{
  position:absolute;
  margin-right:15in
}
```

But since you're applying the class right onto the p you don't need to define what element it is in your css. Hope this helps